# Posting to Facebook with Share Dialog from Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

Can somebody share any links to examples for posting to Facebook from a Windows Forms application using the Facebook SDK or using a URL that displays the "Post to Facebook" dialog to allow the user to fill in a message before clicking the Share button.

I've searched around but all the examples assume either than Javascript is being used or the message is being posted directly using the SDK with no opportunity for the user to provide a message first.

I'm using C# and .NET 4.0 to create a Windows Forms application for this. I've obtained an application ID from Facebook and I can post successfully with this code:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var parameters = new
{
    name = "MyAppName",
    caption = "caption goes here",
    description = "description goes here",
    link = "link goes here",
    picture = "link to picture"
};
fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

I just want it to show the Share dialog rather than post directly. Any suggestions for what I'm missing?